# How to sort by integer in a listitemcollection in WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a listbox which has a sort like this:

```
ListBox.Items.SortDescriptions.Add(new SortDescription("Order", ListSortDirection.Descending));
```

But it sorts alphabetically, not numeric values! 
How to do that?

By the way - the property (aka column) is stored as a varchar in the database and the property is a string. But somehow I would like to convert it to a integer. 
And I tried with a another property and it was an integer and I couldn't sort it at all! It threw an exception!

Comment: What are the items in your list?

Comment: Are you populating the list manually or by binding to a data source?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If this is all the sorting you are going to be doing inside that control, a good option would be to set [`ListCollectionView.CustomSort`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.listcollectionview.customsort.aspx) to an [`IComparer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Collections.IComparer.aspx) instance that does natural sorting. This will couple the implementation to the type of the items in your `ListView`, but if that type is not going to change very often this is a reasonable limitation. On the other hand, the sort will be much faster because it won't need to involve reflection.

Assuming you have such a comparer:

```
var comparer = new ...
```

then all you need to do is install it:

```
var view = (ListCollectionView)
           CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(ListBox.ItemsSource);
view.CustomSort = comparer;
```

That's easy. So now we only have to find out what `comparer` looks like... Here's a [very good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/248603/natural-sort-order-in-c-sharp/248613#248613) showing how to implement such a comparer:

```
[SuppressUnmanagedCodeSecurity]
internal static class SafeNativeMethods
{
    [DllImport("shlwapi.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Unicode)]
    public static extern int StrCmpLogicalW(string psz1, string psz2);
}

public sealed class NaturalOrderComparer : IComparer
{
    public int Compare(object a, object b)
    {
        // replace DataItem with the actual class of the items in the ListView
        var lhs = (DataItem)a;
        var rhs = (DataItem)b;
        return SafeNativeMethods.StrCmpLogicalW(lhs.Order, rhs.Order);
    }
}
```

So, given the comparer above you should find everything working with

```
var view = (ListCollectionView)
           CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(ListBox.ItemsSource);
view.CustomSort = new NaturalOrderComparer();
```